# Int parameter changes to 0 when passing into a method

Tags: ios, swift, methods, parameter-passing

I'm having a really bizarre problem that I'm hoping someone can shed some light on. I have a property at class level which I then pass into a method in another class, at the time of passing the property is equal to what I'm expecting but once passed into the method the value changes to 0? There is no logical reason why this would be happening. Please see below screenshots for more context.

[image: First Method]

[image: Correct Value]

[image: Second Method]

[image: Incorrect Value]

I look forward to hearing your suggestions.

EDIT: As requested, the code is below:

```
Networking.updateExistingEntry(RegistrationDataManager.get.currentRegistrationModel(), entryId: entryId) { (success) -> Void in
    print(success)
}

class func updateExistingEntry(registrationModel: RegistrationModel, entryId: Int, completion:(success: Bool) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.PUT, Routing.Entries().URLByAppendingPathComponent("/\(entryId)"), parameters: registrationModel.map(), encoding: .JSON, headers: ["X-SessionToken":Settings.getSessionToken()!]).validate().responseJSON { (request, response, result) -> Void in
        completion(success: result.isSuccess)
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the actual code, not screenshots of it, they are VERY hard to read.

Comment: How do you invoke `updateExistingEntry `, can you share more code?

Comment: How do you conclude that the value changes to 0?  By inspecting its value in the debugger, or by, let say, printing its value to the console during the execution?

Reason why I ask is that I saw some very weird cases when values I observed during debugging were not really the ones I would observe if I would just print them out.

Comment: Thanks Anton, the method in question then goes and makes a network call using the entryId value, I can see from the backend that 0 is passed in.

Comment: Just because your code takes fewer lines doesn't mean it's better in any way whatsoever.

Comment: nhgriff Im not sure I follow?

Comment: Please print the `entryId` variable at the first line of `updateExistingEntry` method, and show where the `entryId` is assigned before use in `Networking` class

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys, I ended up running the app detached from the debugger (standalone) and using a alertview to 'print' the value of entryId to me; and it was correct! It seems this is an xcode bug. After re-installing xcode everything is now working fine.